# Live streaming an event

Tags: streaming, dslr, live, live-recording

I want to live stream an event on YouTube with my DSLR. Will I need a HDMI capture card? If yes can you please list a few inexpensive ones.

Also, please mention if there are any other ways for me to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need an HDMI capture card.  If you have a modern Mac, you can make do with this $145 device that plugs into its Thunderbolt port: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/ultrastudiothunderbolt/techspecs/W-DLUS-04

Comment: Do you work for Blackmagic?

Comment: No, I don't work for BlackMagic.  You can read my profile here: http://video.stackexchange.com/users/10931/michael-tiemann?tab=profile